# (Parse.com) How to send a push notification with local timezone

Tags: notifications, timezone, parse-platform, cloud, push

I have users from different timezone and I would like to send a push notification automatically by cloud code at a specific time, lets say 20pm.

The problem I have: it's sending the push at 20pm UTC to all, so someone in China or France would not receive it at 20 pm to their local time, but a time corresponding to the 20pm UTC of parse's server if i'm not mistaking.

How can I send a push notification from cloud code to a specific time in respect to each user local time?

Comment: Hi, did you solve the problem?

Comment: nope, I just gave up.

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I've come up with is to create a separate channel for each timezone you want to support, subscribe your users to their appropriate channel, then send push notifications with localized times to each channel.

Note, however, that if China is specifically a country you want to support, they have only one timezone for the entire, very large country that geographically spans five timezones. 8am in Eastern China is also 8am in Western China, even though it should be 3am in Western China.